# rails can't save result in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have some controllers - users, categories, stories and comments. Everything was okay till I did comments. In my DB I want to save content, user_id, story_id but the table is empty. @comment.save is false. Here is part of my code:

CommentsController:

```
def create
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
  @comment = @story.comments.create(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfull added comment"
    redirect_to stories_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

show.html.erb for StoriesController:

```
<b><%= @story.title %></b> <br/><br/>

<%= @story.content %> <br/><br/>

<% @story.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <b>Comment:</b>
  <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for([@story, @story.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In StoriesController I did same thing but now I can't understand how to do it.

```
def create
  @categories = Category.all
  @story = current_user.stories.build(params[:story])
end
```

Comment: Which line specifically is causing the error? Do you have a join set up between stories and comments?

Comment: I don't know how but when I restart the server the problem with the error message was fixed but the Comments table i DB is empty. And I have in story.rb has_many :comments and in comment.rb - belongs_to :story. In route.rb I have:

    resources :stories do
      resources :comments
    end

Comment: Now I have the error message again.. at this line: @comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])

Answer (score 1):

The error:  "undefined method for nil:NilClass" always seems to bite me when I'm assuming that a model/class has been instantiated when it hasn't.  If you are getting this error on the line:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
```

I would guess that your code is being run without a logged-in user, so current_user is nil.  The structure of your @comment code indicates that you are only going to let registered users create comments, so you might try this approach:

```
if current_user
  @comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
else
  redirect :root, :notice => "Sorry you must be registered and logged in to comment"
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changed it how you wrote but the problem is still here when I am logged in. And the error message is on this line, which you guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very stupid! I missed has_many comments in user model..  but now the problem is still here because the content of the comment can't be saved in DB and the table Comments is empty.

@comment.save is false in my case

```
def create
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
  if current_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.create(params[:comment])
  end

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfull added comment"
    redirect_to story_path(@story)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Some things to try:  1)  ensure you added a user_id column and a belongs_to statement for your comments   2)  logic issue: when your first if statement fails the @comment variable will not get created and the second if statement's condition will generate an exception.  3) Make sure all your comments fields are attr_accessible - check the dev log to see if you are getting warnings on this.   4) create a test comment manually in your code and try to save it (don't use ...create(params[:comment])  5) puts() to the server console params[:comment] to see what your form is sending back to you.